# 301 redirect from a country specific domain

Tags: seo, domains, google-search-console, 301-redirect

I originally started using a `.do` domain extension for my site, but later realized that this country specific domain would prevent us from appearing in search results for places outside of the Dominican Republic.

We started using a `.co` domain extension and redirected all requests to the new domain using an HTTP 301.

The "Crawl Stats" in Google Webmaster Tools shows me that the `.co` domain is being crawled, but the "Index Status" shows the number of pages indexed at 0.  The "Crawl Stats" for the `.do` domain says that it's being crawled and the "Index Status" shows a number greater than 0.

I also set a "Change Of Address" in Google Webmaster Tools to have the `.do` domain point to the new `.co` domain.

We're still not appearing in search results at all even for very specific strings where I would expect to find us.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How long ago was the switch over and performed?  Also do you mind sharing your URL?

Comment: It was about 10 days ago that we started issuing the 301 redirects.

Answer (score 1):

> It was about 10 days ago that we started issuing the 301 redirects.

It is too small period for Google.

Google says it takes about 30 days for full recrawling.

If after 1 month the situation will not change, you should check your redirect options.

Comment: What do yo mean by check my redirect options?

Comment: I mean .htaccess options. Have you made URL to URL redirect?

Comment: Yes.  I am not using .htaccess for the 301 redirects.  It's happening in code.

Comment: URL to URL redirect is trully good. Now you can only wait.